# Search array and return sibling value

Tags: php

I'd like to search an array of products by a specific value and return a sibling value. For example, searching for barcode 4325, should return the ID 2135. What is the best way to do this in PHP?

```
$products = array(
   array(
    'id' => 2135,
    'title' => 'Product 1',
    'variants' => array(
        'barcode' => '4325',
     ),
   ),
   array(
    'id' => 234,
    'title' => 'Product 2',
    'variants' => array(
        'barcode' => '2355',
     ),
   )
);
```

Comment: Show your coding attempt before you are downvoted to oblivion.

Comment: I'm not sure you mean *"sibling"*. What it seems you're after is to identify a particular record in an array by a nested property

Answer (score 0):

Simple `foreach` loop

```
$barcode = '4325';

foreach($products as $value) {
    if ($value['variants']['barcode'] === $barcode) {
        echo 'ID = ' . $value['id'];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a no research, no coding attempt, duplicate and shouldn't be answered.  Please remove your answer to show the user that some effort is required.  I expect it will be swiftly closed and deleted anyhow.  If you delete your answer, the OP can retract the question (saving moderation time) and recover lost rep points.